# Getting answers from localhost when running remote script to another client

Tags: powershell

I have made a script (with the help of youtube, SS64 + other resources) and modified it a bit to work on remote servers in my domain environment. I have enabled WinRM and I am able to connect to other Clients/Servers in my network. I have also `Get-ExecutionPolicy` on unrestricted on all clients/servers I am trying to launch my script into.

Problem:

I have laid the block of code in a function and I am using an if/else statement to access either the local machine or a remote machine (using `Enter-PSSession` with the hostname).

When I enter the remote part of my `if`/`else` statement and run my function it looks like it is working normally. I get prompted to login with my username etc, but after I choose "List all processes" or another part of my script it basically lists the results from my local host, and not my remote host. Once I exit the script I check if I am indeed connected to the remote host and it seems that I am, and when I type `Get-Process` it gives my the correct information for that remote server.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here so I'll post the code.

http://textuploader.com/dscz4

```
clear
$PROCESS_ID = 0
$CONFIRM_TERMINATE = "No"
$RUN_AGAIN = "Yes"
$SERVICES = ""
$SERVICE_TO_STOP = ""
$SERVICE_TO_START = ""
$SERVICE_FOUND = "No"
$UserReplyRunningService = ""
$RemoteComputer = ""
$AdminLogin = "administrator"
$LocalorRemote

function scriptmain {
    while ($RUN_AGAIN -eq "Yes" -or $RUN_AGAIN -eq "Y") {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "-----------Select a Menu Item-----------"
        Write-Host "List all processes                   [1]"
        Write-Host "Stop a process                       [2]"
        Write-Host "List all services                    [3]"
        Write-Host "Stop a running service               [4]"
        Write-Host "Start a running service              [5]"
        Write-Host "Script Author                        [6]"
        Write-Host "Quit the program?                    [7]"
        Write-Host ""
        $MY_SELECTION = Read-Host "Enter your selection: "
        Write-Host ""
        switch ($MY_SELECTION) {
            1 {Get-Process}
            2 {
                $PROCESS_ID = Read-Host "What process ID do you want to stop?"
                $PROCESSES = Get-Process
                foreach ($Process in $Processes) {
                    if ($Process.ID -eq $PROCESS_ID) {
                        $CONFIRM_TERMINATE = Write-Host $Process.ProcessName "Will be terminated (Yes/No)"
                        $CONFIRM_TERMINATE = Read-Host "Terminate Process (Yes/No)"
                        if ($CONFIRM_TERMINATE -eq "Yes" -or $CONFIRM_TERMINATE -eq "Y") {
                            Write-Host "Terminate confirmed by the user. Ending process." $Process.ProcessName
                            Stop-Process -Id $PROCESS_ID -Force
                        } else {
                            Write-Host "Terminate not confirmed no action taken."
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            3 {Get-Service}
            4 {
                $SERVICE_FOUND = "No"
                $SERVICE_TO_STOP = Read-Host "What is the Name of the service you would like to stop? (Note: Not the DisplayName)"
                $SERVICES = @(Get-Service)
                foreach ($SERVICE in $SERVICES) {
                    if ($SERVICE.Name -eq $SERVICE_TO_STOP) {
                        if ($SERVICE.Status -eq "Running") {
                            $SERVICE_FOUND = "Yes"
                            Write-Host $SERVICE.Name "Service found."
                            Write-Host "Stopping service now."
                            Stop-Service $SERVICE_TO_STOP -Force
                            Get-Service | ? {$_.Name -eq $SERVICE_TO_STOP}
                        } elseif ($SERVICE.Status -eq "Stopped") {
                            $SERVICE_FOUND = "Yes"
                            Write-Host "The service is already stopped."
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($SERVICE_FOUND -eq "No") {
                    Write-Host "We did not find the service you entered, please try again."
                }
            }
            5 {
                Write-Host "You want to start a running service?"
                $UserReplyRunningService = Read-Host "Yes/No?"
                if ($UserReplyRunningService -eq "Yes" -or $UserReplyRunningService -eq "Y") {
                    $SERVICE_FOUND = "No"
                    $SERVICE_TO_START = Read-Host "What is the Name of the service you would like to start? (Note: Not the DisplayName)"
                    $SERVICES = @(Get-Service)
                    foreach ($SERVICE in $SERVICES) {
                        if ($SERVICE.Name -eq $SERVICE_TO_START) {
                            if ($SERVICE.Status -eq "Stopped") {
                                $SERVICE_FOUND = "Yes"
                                Write-Host $SERVICE.Name "Service found."
                                Write-Host "Starting service now."
                                Start-Service $SERVICE_TO_START
                                Get-Service | ? {$_.Name -eq $SERVICE_TO_START}
                            } elseif ($SERVICE.Status -eq "Running") {
                                $SERVICE_FOUND = "Yes"
                                Write-Host "The service is already running."
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($SERVICE_FOUND -eq "No") {
                        Write-Host "We did not find the service you entered, please try again."
                    }
                } elseif($UserReplyRunningService -eq "No") {
                    $RUN_AGAIN = Read-Host "Type 'Yes' or 'No' to run the program again"
                }
            }
            6 {Write-Host "Script made by 'blablabla' @ 31.08.2016"}
            7 {exit}
            default {"Error you did not select a valid option"}
        }
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host ""
        $RUN_AGAIN = Read-Host "Type 'Yes' or 'No' to run the program again"
    }
}

Write-Host "Local or Remote PC?"
Write-Host ""
$LocalorRemote = Read-Host "Type Local/Remote"
if ($LocalorRemote -eq "Local" -or $LocalorRemote -eq "L") {
    scriptmain
} elseif ($LocalorRemote -eq "Remote" -or $LocalorRemote -eq "R") {
    Write-Host "Type in the host-name of the computer you would like to remote into:"
    $RemoteComputer = Read-Host "Type the Host-Name"
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteComputer -Credential $AdminLogin
    scriptmain
} else {
    Write-Host "Invalid"
}
```

Comment: Please include your code in your question. Do not put it on some external site that may disappear at any given time. Also reduce the code to the smallest sample that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Added the code. I'll try to shrink it too.

Comment: Are you running the script or dot sourcing it into an interactive session?

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` does not change session where rest of script executes.